# Seed Method in EF Code-First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use EF's Seed method to fill my database with some sample data, but when I try to run it the data isn't being populated.

Anyone know why? 
Thanks.

DBContext:

```
public void Seed(EFloristEntities context)
{
    new List<Product>
    {
        new Product() { Id = 1, ProductName = "Product 1", ProductDescription = "a", Price = 1.0}
    }.ForEach(i => context.Products.Add(i));

    context.SaveChanges();
}

public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
public DbSet<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
```

My Initializer:

```
public class CreateInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EFloristEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(EFloristEntities context)
    {
        context.Seed(context);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Global.aspx:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFloristEntities>()); 
new EFloristEntities().Database.CreateIfNotExists();

Database.SetInitializer(new CreateInitializer());
```

Comment: Ehm... `global.aspx`? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing your database at all in your Global file. You need to run the following code:

`EFloristEntities.Database.Initialize(true)`

And I would recommend, if you want to use your custom initializer, that you place this code underneath that `Database.SetInitializer(new CreateInitializer())` call.

Comment: I tested this without success :( using (var context = new EFloristEntities())
            {
                context.Database.Initialize(true);
            }

Comment: Has your database been created already? If so, you'll need to use a different initializer (like @kpadmanabhan above)

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the intializer to use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. Try substituting it with DropCreateDatabaseAlways once.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the base initializer AFTER you call your own Seed code.